# How to prevent duplicates in array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program where you can't add a new employee with the same ID that is already taken. But with this code it adds the employee anyways. Any suggestions to how I can change my code?

Also the array is supposed to hold a maximum of 10 employees.

I´ll gladly provide any more information if needed.

```
for (Employee employee : employeeArray) {
    if (employee != null && employee.getEmployeeID().equals(eID)) {
        counter = employeeArray.length - 1;
        System.out.println("An employee with " + eID + " is already in your collection");

    } else if (counter < 10) {
        employeeArray[counter] = e_obj;
        counter++;
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Set`....

Comment: What's inside eID (what kind of object)?

Comment: @gscaparrotti its a string

Comment: With `counter = employeArr.length - 1;` you will override the last array entry when entering the second case `employeArr[counter] = e_obj;`. In the first case, the counter should remain unchanged.

Comment: You can use Set for a single value or HashMap for pair. That prevents duplicates

Comment: change your if condition to if (employe != null && !employe.getEmployeID().equals(eID)) { // place your code inside this to add new employee}. and why you are using counter = employeArr.length - 1;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
// Check if the employee already exists

boolean isExisting = false;

for (Employe employe : employeArr) {
    if (employe != null && employe.getEmployeID() != null && employe.getEmployeID().equals(eID)) {
        isExisting = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!isExisting) {
    // Your existing logic to add the employee
}
```

Comment: You can use `eID.equals(employee...)` or [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) instead of doing the second null check manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use HashSet instead of this. just create an object of HashSet or set and it will not accept any duplicate values from you.

Answer (score 1):

If getEmployeeID returns a String and compares it to a String eID I suggest seeing if there might be extra white space or a case sensitivity issue.

```
if (employee != null && employee.getEmployeeID().equals(eID)) {
```

Also, you shouldn't need to adjust the counter in the if clause.

```
counter = employeeArray.length - 1;
```